# GSA Search - query syntax

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am trying to create a query for GSA Search:

The query suppose to bring all the results that exclude some texts inside meta tag, some thing like:

```
inmeta:Education -first and -second and -courses...
```

But no luck with that. Is anybody knows what the right syntax is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the equal to condition before and the query looks like this -

```
(inmeta:education=first OR inmeta:education=second)
```

If your results must not include all the pages with the meta tag `Education` not equal to the value `first` then use -

```
inmeta:Education-first
```

For multiple values you can use the OR condition -

```
(inmeta:Education-first OR inmeta:Education-second)
```

You can find a lot more information here - 
https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/xml_reference#request_query_terms

Hope this helps you.